# geodesic distance transform in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distance

In python there is the `distance_transform_edt` function in the `scipy.ndimage.morphology` module. I applied it to a simple case, to compute the distance from a single cell in a masked numpy array.

However the function remove the mask of the array and compute, as expected, the Euclidean distance for each cell, with non null value, from the reference cell, with the null value.

Below is an example I gave in [my blog post](http://bloggb.fr/python/2015/01/26/geodesic-distance-transform-in-python.html):

```
%pylab
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt
l = 100
x, y = np.indices((l, l))
center1 = (50, 20)
center2 = (28, 24)
center3 = (30, 50)
center4 = (60,48)
radius1, radius2, radius3, radius4 = 15, 12, 19, 12
circle1 = (x - center1[0])**2 + (y - center1[1])**2 < radius1**2
circle2 = (x - center2[0])**2 + (y - center2[1])**2 < radius2**2
circle3 = (x - center3[0])**2 + (y - center3[1])**2 < radius3**2
circle4 = (x - center4[0])**2 + (y - center4[1])**2 < radius4**2
# 3 circles
img = circle1 + circle2 + circle3 + circle4
mask = ~img.astype(bool)
img = img.astype(float)
m = ones_like(img)
m[center1] = 0
#imshow(distance_transform_edt(m), interpolation='nearest')
m = ma.masked_array(distance_transform_edt(m), mask)
imshow(m, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image: Euclidean distance transform]

However I want to compute the geodesic distance transform that take into account the masked elements of the array. I do not want to compute the Euclidean distance along a straight line that go through masked elements.

I used The Dijkstra algorithm to obtain the result I want. Below is the implementation I proposed:

```
def geodesic_distance_transform(m):
    mask = m.mask
    visit_mask = mask.copy() # mask visited cells
    m = m.filled(numpy.inf)
    m[m!=0] = numpy.inf
    distance_increments = numpy.asarray([sqrt(2), 1., sqrt(2), 1., 1., sqrt(2), 1., sqrt(2)])
    connectivity = [(i,j) for i in [-1, 0, 1] for j in [-1, 0, 1] if (not (i == j == 0))]
    cc = unravel_index(m.argmin(), m.shape) # current_cell
    while (~visit_mask).sum() > 0:
        neighbors = [tuple(e) for e in asarray(cc) - connectivity 
                     if not visit_mask[tuple(e)]]
        tentative_distance = [distance_increments[i] for i,e in enumerate(asarray(cc) - connectivity) 
                              if not visit_mask[tuple(e)]]
        for i,e in enumerate(neighbors):
            d = tentative_distance[i] + m[cc]
            if d < m[e]:
                m[e] = d
        visit_mask[cc] = True
        m_mask = ma.masked_array(m, visit_mask)
        cc = unravel_index(m_mask.argmin(), m.shape)
    return m

gdt = geodesic_distance_transform(m)
imshow(gdt, interpolation='nearest')
colorbar()
```

[image]

The function implemented above works well but is too slow for the application I developed which needs to compute the geodesic distance transform several times.

Below is the time benchmark of the euclidean distance transform and the geodesic distance transform:

```
%timeit distance_transform_edt(m)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

%timeit geodesic_distance_transform(m)
1 loops, best of 3: 702 ms per loop
```

How can I obtained a faster geodesic distance transform?

Comment: `distance_transform_edt` doesn't give what you want, but your `m` is also never masked, before feeding into the function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, thumbs up for a very clear and well written question.

There is a very good and fast implementation of a `Fast Marching` method called `scikit-fmm` to solve this kind of problem. You can find the details here:
http://pythonhosted.org//scikit-fmm/

Installing it might be the hardest part, but on Windows with Conda its easy, since there is 64bit Conda package for Py27:
https://binstar.org/jmargeta/scikit-fmm

From there on, just pass your masked array to it, as you do with your own function. Like:

```
distance = skfmm.distance(m)
```

The results looks similar, and i think even slightly better. Your approach searches (apparently) in eight distinct directions resulting in a bit of a 'octagonal-shaped` distance.

[image]

On my machine the scikit-fmm implementation is over 200x faster then your function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the method. The result looks very good and fast. That's what I want! However, the only hard point is the installation. For the moment I didn't succeed to compile and I would prefer a solution using more standard python libraries to facilitate the distribution of the code.

Comment: I used this method too but there are differences in the calculation of the distance competing it with the scipy edt function. For example if I i have a grid space of 0.5 and i want to calculate the distance of a point to all surround points the diagonal cells have a distance of 0.70710678 in the scipy edt version and 0.85355339 with the scikit fmm version. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4):

64-bit Windows binaries for scikit-fmm are now available from Christoph Gohlke.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-fmm

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster (about 10x) implementation that achieves the same result as your `geodesic_distance_transform`:

```
def getMissingMask(slab):

    nan_mask=numpy.where(numpy.isnan(slab),1,0)
    if not hasattr(slab,'mask'):
        mask_mask=numpy.zeros(slab.shape)
    else:
        if slab.mask.size==1 and slab.mask==False:
            mask_mask=numpy.zeros(slab.shape)
        else:
            mask_mask=numpy.where(slab.mask,1,0)
    mask=numpy.where(mask_mask+nan_mask>0,1,0)

    return mask

def geodesic(img,seed):

    seedy,seedx=seed
    mask=getMissingMask(img)

    #----Call distance_transform_edt if no missing----
    if mask.sum()==0:
        slab=numpy.ones(img.shape)
        slab[seedy,seedx]=0
        return distance_transform_edt(slab)

    target=(1-mask).sum()
    dist=numpy.ones(img.shape)*numpy.inf
    dist[seedy,seedx]=0

    def expandDir(img,direction):
        if direction=='n':
            l1=img[0,:]
            img=numpy.roll(img,1,axis=0)
            img[0,:]==l1
        elif direction=='s':
            l1=img[-1,:]
            img=numpy.roll(img,-1,axis=0)
            img[-1,:]==l1
        elif direction=='e':
            l1=img[:,0]
            img=numpy.roll(img,1,axis=1)
            img[:,0]=l1
        elif direction=='w':
            l1=img[:,-1]
            img=numpy.roll(img,-1,axis=1)
            img[:,-1]==l1
        elif direction=='ne':
            img=expandDir(img,'n')
            img=expandDir(img,'e')
        elif direction=='nw':
            img=expandDir(img,'n')
            img=expandDir(img,'w')
        elif direction=='sw':
            img=expandDir(img,'s')
            img=expandDir(img,'w')
        elif direction=='se':
            img=expandDir(img,'s')
            img=expandDir(img,'e')

        return img

    def expandIter(img):
        sqrt2=numpy.sqrt(2)
        tmps=[]
        for dirii,dd in zip(['n','s','e','w','ne','nw','sw','se'],\
                [1,]*4+[sqrt2,]*4):
            tmpii=expandDir(img,dirii)+dd
            tmpii=numpy.minimum(tmpii,img)
            tmps.append(tmpii)
        img=reduce(lambda x,y:numpy.minimum(x,y),tmps)

        return img

    #----------------Iteratively expand----------------
    dist_old=dist
    while True:
        expand=expandIter(dist)
        dist=numpy.where(mask,dist,expand)
        nc=dist.size-len(numpy.where(dist==numpy.inf)[0])

        if nc>=target or numpy.all(dist_old==dist):
            break
        dist_old=dist

    return dist
```

Also note that if the mask forms more than 1 connected regions (e.g. adding another circle not touching the others), your function will fall into an endless loop.

**UPDATE**:

I found one Cython implementation of Fast Sweeping method [in this notebook](https://github.com/znah/notebooks/blob/master/geodesic.ipynb), which can be used to achieve the same result as `scikit-fmm` with probably comparable speed. One just need to feed a binary flag matrix (with 1s as viable points, `inf` otherwise) as the cost to the `GDT()` function.